# Send uploaded image to a view and show inside an img tag

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am new to Laravel and am working with the image uploading mechanism. I succeeded in uploading and validating an image, but can't figure out how to send it with a view to show.

I have a controller called `userController`. Inside `resource/views/user` directory I have three of the following blade templates, they are:

1. index.blade.php
2. create.blade.php
3. store.blade.php

I have my PHP form inside `create.blade.php`. After submitting the form I want to send the uploaded image to `index.blade.php`. How can achieve this?

**store() method of userController:**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $data = Input::all();



        $rules = array(
           'name' => 'unique:users,name|required|alpha_num',
           'password'=>'required',
           'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|required|max:100'
        );

        // Create a new validator instance.
        $validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
        if($validator->fails()){

            $errors=$validator->messages();
            return Redirect::route('user.create')->withErrors($validator);

        }else{

            if(Input::hasFile('image')){
                $file=Input::file('image');
                $file->move('uploads',$file->getClientOriginalName());
                return Redirect::route('user.index')->with(file); // tried this but don't know whether it will work or not 
            }

        }

    }
```

**index.blade.php page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  // i want to show the uploaded image here

<h1>Hi this is index </h1>
<a href="{{ URL::to('user/create') }}">Create a task</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the return statement,

```
$image = $file->getClientOriginalName() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtention(); 

Session::flash('image', 'uploads/' . $image); 

return Redirect::route('user');
```

And in

```
Public function index()
{
   If(Session::has('image'))
    {
       return view('user.index')->with(compact('image'));
     }
}
```

In ur head index blade file

```
<img src="{!!$image!!}">
```